# How do I show an in app purchase price in local currency

Tags: coronasdk

Just wondering what I need to call to show the price in local currency of my in app purchase.  Eg, in Australia I would like to have a button / label that shows $1.29 (tier 1) but if somebody in North America is using the app, it will show $0.99 (tier 1).

This is for iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the store library, you can call the function "loadProducts" to get the available items for sale. Each item entry has a field "localizedPrice" that is a string representing the price according to the user's apple store.

for example, for ios:

```
local productIds = { 
    --array of your product identifiers, as you defined them in iTunes Connect 
}

local function loadProductsCallback( event )
    local validProducts = event.products
    local invalidProducts = event.invalidProducts
    if validProducts ~= nil then
        for i = 1, #validProducts do
            local currentItem = validProducts[i]
            -- here do what you want with currentItem.localizedPrice 
        end
    end
end

local store = require("store")
store.init("apple", storeListener)
if store.isActive and store.canLoadProducts then
    store.loadProducts(productIds, loadProductsCallback)
End
```

You can read more about it in the documentation:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/store/loadProducts.html

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Yep, I read about that just today but again, thanks for the time in putting up the answer.